# The dual semigroup is equivalent in norm to its original semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I would like to show the following inequality regarding the dual semigroup of a semigroup of linear operators (the one at the end of the image). The screenshot comes from the book One-paramter Semigroups of Positive Operators of Arendt et al.

[image: Arendt et al]

I have troubles understanding why
$$
||f||\leq M \sup\{\langle f, \phi \rangle \mid \phi\in E^*, ||\phi||\leq 1\}.
$$
They write that one should consider $\int_0^t{T'_s \phi}dt$ understood in a weak sense, i.e. as a map $f\mapsto \int_0^t{T'_s \phi(f)}dt$. So first of all I think one needs to consider $\psi_t=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t{T'_s \phi}dt$ since $\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t{T_tf}dt\rightarrow f$ strongly. So I tried the following
$$
||f||\leq||\int_0^t{T_tf-f}dt||+||\int_0^t{T_tf}dt||.
$$

The first term on the righthandside above goes to $0$ hence is smaller than an $\varepsilon$. However hard we try we cannot estimate the second term with $||\psi_t||$.

Another idea I had was to use Hahn-Banach to find a $\phi$ with $||\phi||=||f||$. Since we are only interested in $f$ with $||f||\leq 1$ this shouldn't be a problem. But we don't really want the $||\cdot||$-norm of $E'$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: @Shaun Especially not in this ugly outdated font :P

Comment: @Shaun I think it was the best possible way to quickly summarise the knowledge needed to help me with the question.

Comment: @QuantumSpace well, that's true, but the book is quite good. No idea why they had to choose such a bad font :-)

Comment: No, images of text are generally discouraged because they're not searchable, sometimes they don't render, and they're not compatible with screen readers.

Comment: @Shaun I see the point, but I am too lazy. Edit the question and type the text if it bothers you, I mean I got an answer.

Comment: @Proxava This is a common font for older math books.

Comment: @Proxava I'm pretty sure they didn't *choose* this font, but it was written on a typewriter. That was common for a certain period starting sometime after the second world war and ending with the widespread use of (La) Tex. It allowed to mass produce books at much cheaper costs. If you take a look at much older books, they often look much better in terms of typesetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\psi_t$ be as in the question with $\|\phi\|\leq 1$. We have $\psi_t\in E^\ast$ and
$$
\|\psi_t\|\leq \frac 1 t\int_0^t \|T_s'\phi\|\,ds\leq \frac 1 t\int_0^t\|T_s\|\,ds.
$$
In particular, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $T\geq 0$ such that $\|\psi_t\|\leq M+\epsilon$ for $t<T$.

Thus
$$
\phi(f)=\lim_{t\searrow 0}\psi_t(f)\leq (M+\epsilon)\sup\{\psi(f)\mid\psi\in E^\ast,\,\|\psi\|\leq 1\}
$$
for every $\epsilon>0$, which implies
$$
\|f\|=\sup\{\phi(f)\mid \phi\in E',\|\phi\|\leq1\}\leq M\sup\{\psi(f)\mid\psi\in E^\ast,\,\|\psi\|\leq 1\}.
$$

Comment: How do you get $\lim_{t\searrow0}\psi_t(f)\leq(M+\varepsilon)\sup\{\psi(f)\mid\psi\in E^*,||\psi|| \leq 1\}$? I mean I can see why $\psi_t(f)\leq ||\psi_t||$, but how we get the $\sup$ into the game?

Comment: For $t$ sufficiently small, $\psi_t/(M+\epsilon)$ is an element of the set over which you take the supremum on the right side. That's what I proved in the paragraph before.

Comment: One small bonus question. How can I see that $\psi_t\in X^*$? I have tried to plug in the definition, but the strong norm on the dual somehow boils down to requiring the semigroup to be uniformly continuous, which is here however not the case.

Comment: That's essentially the same argument as one uses to show that $\int_0^t T_s x\,ds$ is in the domain of the generator.

Comment: If I try to reproduce this argument, I have the problem that the strong norm on $X'$ given by $||\phi||=sup_{||u||\leq 1}{ |\phi(u)| }$ somehow doesn't work. I mean consider $||T'_s\psi_t-\psi_t||\leq...\leq\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t{||T_{s+t}-T_s||ds}$ which does not go to $0$ for general (non-uniformly continuous) semigroups. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know how exactly you came to that, but one obvious problem is that $s$ is a free variable on the left and the integration variable on the right. You get $T_s'\psi_t=\int_t^{s+t}T_r'\phi\,dr-\int_0^sT_r'\phi\,dr$, and each summand goes to zero in norm.